# Make chosen player stand out from other players on scoreboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little game I play around with to learn Javascript better.

The player gets to choose

So i'm doing a little dice game in javascript/jquery. I get some users (In this case players) from a REST API that i get with AJAX Like this:

```
var APICaller = (function () {
    let endpoint = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";

    function api_call(method, url, data, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: method,
            data: data,
            success: callback
        });
    }

    function get_users(callback) {
        let method = "GET";
        let url = endpoint + "users";
        let data = {};
        api_call(method, url, data, callback);
    }

    return {
        get_users: get_users,
    };
})();
```

The person playing the game can choose a player from the user list and then press the play button.

When the play button is pressed the dice should roll 3 numbers for each player and display all the numbers at the side of each player. And then the dice value list should change after a time and only the total amount of the three dice values should be in that list, and also the user list should be in points order with the highest total points on the top.

I have manage to solve all of those problems but I just need guidance of how to make the player I choose to have a green background color in the final score board.

This is how my code looks like:

```
var players = [];
var currentPlayer;

function add_scoreboard() {
    $("#my-list").css({
        display: 'none'
    });
    $("#my-list2").css({
        display: 'block'
    });

    // currentPlayer.style.background("green");

    let elements = []
    let container = document.querySelector('#main_gameDiv')
    //Add each row to the array
    container.querySelectorAll('.list-li2').forEach(el => elements.push(el))
    //Clear the container
    container.innerHTML = ''
    //Sort the array from highest to lowest
    elements.sort((a, b) => b.querySelector('.score').textContent - a.querySelector('.score').textContent)
    //Put the elements back into the container
    elements.forEach(e => container.appendChild(e))
        if(elements.firstchild.data == currentPlayer.firstchild.data){
            $(this).css({background: 'green'});
        }
    console.log(elements);
}

var EventHandlers = (function () {
    function init() {
        APICaller.get_users(on_get_users_success);

        function on_get_users_success(response) {
            //For each user in the API
            $.each(response, function (i, user) {

                $("#my-list").append('<li class="list-li"><a class="list-a">' + user.name + '</a><span class="score"></span></li>');

                $("#my-list2").append('<li class="list-li2">' + user.name + '<span class="score"></span></li>');

                var playerObject = {
                    id: user.id,
                    name: user.name,
                    score: 0
                };
                //Add all objects to the array
                players.push(playerObject);

            });
            $("#my-list2").css({
                display: 'none'
            });
            //change information
            $("#info-txt").text("Välj en spelare!");
        }
        // On klick on a user make klicked user your own player.
        $("#my-list").on('click', '.list-a', function () {
            currentPlayer = this;

            $("#info-txt").text("Tryck på spela knappen för att börja spelet!");
            $("#currentPlayer-div").animate({
                height: '300px',
                opacity: '1'
            });
            $("#currentPlayer-h3").text(this.text);

        });
        // On klick of the play button
        $("#startGame-button").click(function () {
            $("#info-txt").text("Vänta 5 sekunder tills scoreboarden visas :)");

            setTimeout(function () {
                add_scoreboard();
            }, 5000);

            $("#my-list2").css({
                display: 'none'
            });

            console.log(players);//Show players in console just for extra info
            $(".score").animate({
                opacity: '1'
            });

            $("#currentPlayer-div").animate({
                height: '150px'
            });
            $("#startGame-button").animate({
                opacity: '0'
            });
            $("#dice_value").animate({
                opacity: '1'
            });

            $("#my-list li").each(function (index) {
                var numbers = [];

                var v1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                var v2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                var v3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                //Add the numbers to the array
                numbers.push(v1, v2, v3);

                var totalScore = numbers.reduce(function (a, b) {
                    return a + b;
                }, 0); //Count the sum of the array

                //Set the players points to the sum of the array
                players[index].score = totalScore;

                //Find every list item of type span and set HTML to the content of the array 
                $(this).find(".score").html(numbers.toString());
            });

            $("#my-list2 li").each(function (index) {
                var numbers = [];

                var v1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                var v2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                var v3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                //Add the numbers to the array
                numbers.push(v1, v2, v3);

                var totalScore = numbers.reduce(function (a, b) {
                    return a + b;
                }, 0); //Count the sum of the array

                //Set the players points to the sum of the array
                players[index].score = totalScore;

                //Find every list item of type span and set HTML to the content of the array 
                $(this).find(".score").html(totalScore.toString()); 
            });
        });
    }

    return {
        init: init,
    }

})();
$(document).ready(function () {
    EventHandlers.init();
});
```

This is where i choose the player:

```
// On klick on a user make klicked user your own player.
        $("#my-list").on('click', '.list-a', function () {
            currentPlayer = this;

            $("#info-txt").text("Tryck på spela knappen för att börja spelet!");
            $("#currentPlayer-div").animate({
                height: '300px',
                opacity: '1'
            });
            $("#currentPlayer-h3").text(this.text);

        });
```

And this is where I try to set the color on that:

```
function add_scoreboard() {
    $("#my-list").css({
        display: 'none'
    });
    $("#my-list2").css({
        display: 'block'
    });

    // currentPlayer.style.background("green");

    let elements = []
    let container = document.querySelector('#main_gameDiv')
    //Add each row to the array
    container.querySelectorAll('.list-li2').forEach(el => elements.push(el))
    //Clear the container
    container.innerHTML = ''
    //Sort the array from highest to lowest
    elements.sort((a, b) => b.querySelector('.score').textContent - a.querySelector('.score').textContent)
    //Put the elements back into the container
    elements.forEach(e => container.appendChild(e))
        if(elements.firstchild.data == currentPlayer.firstchild.data){
            $(this).css({background: 'green'});
        }
    console.log(elements);
}
```

I think it is `if(elements.firstchild.data == currentPlayer.firstchild.data){ $(this).css({background: 'green'}); }` and i know there is a problem because it is not changing background color.

Hope that describes it enough.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You did a good job explaining your game, but where exactly in the code you pasted do you think the problem is? and why do you think there is a problem?

Comment: I think it is `if(elements.firstchild.data == currentPlayer.firstchild.data){
            $(this).css({background: 'green'});
        }` and i know there is a problem because it is not changing background color @AndrewLohr

Comment: do you have any errors in the browsers dev console? `elements` is an array, right? I don't think `elements.firstchild` would work, is that right?

Comment: Yeah i get a error that says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` so i think that you are right @AndrewLohr

Answer (score 0):

Since `elements` is an array it doesn't have a property `firstchild` so that is why you get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`. It seems like what you want is to include that code in your `elements.forEach` function.

For example:

```
//Put the elements back into the container
elements.forEach(e => {
  container.appendChild(e);
  if (e.firstchild.data == currentPlayer.firstchild.data) {
    $(e).css({
      background: 'green'
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! when I run your example it is only one of the elements that shows up

Comment: does the `elements` array have more than 1 element in it? Are there any other errors in the dev console?

Comment: It works if i get it in a new exact same foreach but then every element gets green

Comment: no errors and yes it have 10  elements in the array

Comment: double check if your conditional works `e.firstchild.data == currentPlayer.firstchild.data`

Comment: Yeah i removed data because that is the thing that wasn't readed right

Comment: If you look at where I set the value of `currentPlayer` to `this`, do you know if that can be a problem :)

Comment: what does `my-list` look like? that's the value of currentPlayer, right? it would be helpful to see the markup for it